# Php time() command giving incorrect time

Tags: php, html

Everytime I echo time() within my php file it returns an incorrect date.  For example echoing time() now would output December 23 2PM when it is December 22nd 11pm.  Any ideas?  Is it something that needs to be reconfigured in the php settings, my computer macosx is set to the correct date also.

---

I've set the default time zone and then did phpinfo() and it states the timezone is set to what ever i set it to but it still gives me the same result no matter what time zone I use.

Comment: is your computer set to the correct time zone?

Comment: `time()` doesn't print a date. It prints a unix timestamp. That timestamp has nothing to do with time zones. As long as the clock is set to a valid time in any time zone, `time()` will print the universally correct UNIX time stamp. You are probably talking about the `date()` function, which is dependent on the timezone.

Answer (score 3):

The time() always returns time stamp that is timezone independent (=UTC). Output of time() should be something like this : 1293079226. it won't print like December 23 2PM....

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your timezone!

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side script, meaning that it is ran from the server. If the date is wrong then it is most likely because the date on the server is wrong, not your computer. If you have access to php.ini then look for the date.timezone setting and make sure it is set to your desired timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('your timezone');
echo time();
```

Comment: I've set the default time zone and then did phpinfo() and it states the timezone is set to what ever i set it to but it still gives me the same result no matter what time zone I use.

Answer (score 0):

```
putenv ('TZ=Asia/calcutta');
```

strtotime(1293084000(unixtimestamp));
   echo date("Y-m-d");

Comment: How can I get the date in unix time stamp instead of normal format